# Sin offering for Zavah?

Tags: sin, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, korban, niddah

[Vayikra 15:30](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9916#v=30&showrashi=true), "And the kohen shall make one into a sin offering and one into a burnt offering, and the kohen shall effect atonement for her, before the Lord, from the uncleanness of her discharge."

What sin?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57512

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the question originally conflated a *zavah* with woman who is *niddah*, this obligation applies to a woman who is experiencing discharge beyond her regular menstrual cycle. Regarding the offering brought by a *Zav*, the male counterpart of a *Zavah*, the *Ibn Ezra* on Lev. 15:15 explains that an offering is brought because such discharges are divine punishment for sin. The *Ramban*  adds that the offering expiates the sin to avoid recurrence.

Comment: @yirmiyahu what is the process for zav/zava since there is no korban these days?

Comment: @alicefine They just owe the Korban for later. Until they bring it they are mostly pure, except for eating Korbanot.